# OSError: [WinError 10013] Сделана попытка доступа к сокету методом, запрещенным правами доступа, как решить ошибку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

Подскажите, в чем проблема?
Мне нужно, чтобы программа запускалась в любой системе без ошибок и чтобы не ругался firewall и антивирус

```
connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection.connect(("10.0.2.15", 12345))
```

Проблему находит в этих строках, уже кучу портов перепробовал, не помогает, антивирус отключен, брандмауэр тоже off

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sockettest.py", line 10, in <module>
    connection.connect(("10.0.2.15", 12345))
OSError: [WinError 10013] Сделана попытка доступа к сокету методом, запрещенным правами доступа
```

Comment: Лог покажите пожалуйста

Comment: Какой лог? Не совсем понимаю

Comment: Полный трейсбек ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sockettest.py", line 10, in <module>
    connection.connect(("10.0.2.15", 12345))
OSError: [WinError 10013] Сделана попытка доступа к сокету методом, запрещенным правами доступа

Comment: Добавил, извиняюсь если не грамотно оформляю вопросы

Answer (score 10):

Была такая же проблема, при этом порт был свободен.

Помог перезапуск сетевой службы (PowerShell от имени администратора):

```
net stop hns; net start hns
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите какой процесс сидит на этом порту и через диспетчер задач завершите процесс. Скорее всего веб-сервер слушает порты.

Comment: Процесс сидел на этом порту! СПС!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score -2):

У меня долго воспроизводилась такая же проблема , правда с raw сокетами, пока не попробовал запустить pyCharm с правами администратора.