# Python Flask - проблема доступа к серверу

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, port

Создаю сервер flask на 55550 порту

- брандмауэр выключил (win 10)
- правило для портов создал (открыл в настройках винды Монитор брандмауэра-> Правило для входящих подключений)
- антивирус штатный отключен, другого антивируса нет
- этот порт через cmd -> netstat -aon никто не слушает и не использует

Если меняю порт, начинает работать какое-то время, потом по новой

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()

    from argparse import ArgumentParser

    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', default=55550, type=int, help='port to listen on')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    port = args.port

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Egor/YandexDisk/python/medoed/main.py", line 248, in <module>
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 841, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 814, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 774, in inner
    fd=fd)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 666, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 577, in __init__
    self.address_family), handler)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\server.py", line 136, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 467, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [WinError 10013] Сделана попытка доступа к сокету методом, запрещенным правами доступа
```

Думаю сделать просто перехват ошибки try except, и ставить другой порт, но костыль очень не хочется делать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1115283/201445 ?

Comment: @gil9red, нет, написал в сабже, что проверил это netstat -aon

Comment: А мне кажется чтото вроде зомби висит от прошлого запуска.

Comment: @eri,да, скорее всего так и есть, так как после какого-то времени и перезапусков. как проверить этих зомби?

Comment: попробуй закрыть браузер чтоб зомби соединение разорвалось

Comment: @eri, да, сработало, неожиданный поворот)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Соединение остается отрытым и поэтому не получается занять порт. Нужно закрыть клиента - браузер, если к нему не попал разрыв соединения при завершении сервера. Браузеры иногда оставляют соединения открытыми для более быстрого доступа к данным.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте запустить ваш сервер с правами администратора.

Возможно, проблема в том, что сокет можно сделать только с правами суперюзера/администратора.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать в качестве хоста свой IP

```
app.run(host='192.168.0.100', port=port)
```